# Keycloak Gatekeeper can't refresh tokens due to CORS

Tags: cors, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

I have a Keycloak Gatekeeper proxy (https://localhost:8080) in front of my application (http://localhost:8081) to offload OAuth2. It connects against a Keycloak server (https://keycloak.my.company). Login and accessing the app through Gatekeeper works fine.

Now I have an AJAX snippet that is executed every 10s to reload certain content. This works only until the JWT life time is exceeded. Then Gatekeeper sends a redirect to Keycloak (as it's supposed to do) but the AJAX request can't follow it due to a CORS error.

The requests look like this:

```
OPTIONS https://keycloak.my.company/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/auth
        ? client_id=demo-app-spring
        & redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Foauth%2Fcallback
        & response_type=code
        & scope=openid+email+profile
        & state=33a3da4d-1c83-4363-857c-511b26706649

    Host: keycloak.my.company
    User-Agent: ...
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Language: ...
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
    Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
    Origin: http://localhost:8080
    DNT: 1
    Connection: keep-alive
```

The response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Length: 93
    Content-Type: application/json
    Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2020 14:20:33 GMT
    Set-Cookie: _0bc78=http://172.26.12.34:8080; Path=/
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Firefox tells me:

> Quellübergreifende (Cross-Origin) Anfrage blockiert: Die
>   Gleiche-Quelle-Regel verbietet das Lesen der externen Ressource auf
>   https://keycloak.my.company/auth/realms/demo/p…nid+email+profile&state=c758c30a-1c1c-46f7-9155-f71b906ac61a.
>   (Grund: CORS-Kopfzeile 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' fehlt).

(translated: Blocked as Same-Origin-Policy forbids reading the resource. Reason CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is missing)

Questions that come to my mind:

1. Why doesn't count the Redirect as "CORS simple request", because of the X-Requested-With header?
2. Why doesn't Keycloak answer the CORS request? It has "+" as CORS Origin and the "https://localhost:8080/*" as Valid Redirect URL
3. Is this the correct way to refresh a token after all? Or does the standard mandate that the client (Javascript) checks the Time To Live and refreshes the JWT *before* it does the actual request?

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Edit:
The configuration:

```
verbose: true

listen: :8080
redirection-url: https://localhost:8080

tls-cert: local/localhost.crt
tls-private-key: local/localhost.key

upstream-url: http://localhost:8081/
skip-upstream-tls-verify: true

client-id: demo-app-spring
client-secret: xxx
discovery-url: https://keycloak.my.company/auth/realms/internal

secure-cookie: true

enable-logging: true

enable-refresh-tokens: true
encryption-key: xxx
store-url: redis://localhost:6379/

enable-default-deny: true
resources:
  - uri: /
    white-listed: true
   ...

enable-cors: true
cors-origins:
 - 'https://localhost:8080'
 ...
cors-methods:
 - GET
 - POST
 - OPTIONS
 - DELETE
 - PUT
cors-headers:
 - authorization
 - content-type
 - Cookie
 - authorization
 - content-type
 - accept
 - x-requested-with
 - origin
 - referer
```

My first attempts were without redis. With Redis I now run into the very issues described in https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-11077

Comment: That's not a token refresh, but access token request. It looks like problem in your keycloak-gateway configuration. Could you add that config to the question, pls?

Comment: You have enabled refresh token, so why it is not used? What is in the logs as a reason?

Comment: Thanks for your input, we found a hint for the expired refresh token in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, there were two problems:

1. Du to https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-11077 Redis had to be disabled
2. In Keycloak under Realm Settings -> Tokens, the "SSO Session Idle" was set to the same value as the "Access Token Lifespan", rendering it useless as it, too, was already expired when the refresh was needed.